# Why does CI load Table Library returns error 500 is currently unable to handle this request?

Tags: codeigniter

So I have this problem for a while now, I already tried to figure it out but I can't found where's the problem. and I already tried to find the solution on the google and forums, but can't found the answer.

I have 2 controllers, let's say `Controller A` & `Controller B`,

Controller A can call function `export_table` without problem, but Controller B cannot call the same function which is `export_table`. Controller B returns a **HTTP ERROR 500 error**, but Controller A just fine and show the data perfectly.

this function contains only

```
$this->ci->load->library('table');
```

for troubleshooting only.

But why does this happened?

CI version i'm using is: `3.0.0`

**Edited:**

Even only call

```
$this->load->library('table');
```

in Controller B will result a HTTP error 500

**Edited:**

controller/Report.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH') ) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Report extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index(){
            // Bunch of query and data that returns data into $data
            $this->myci->get_report_table($data);
        }
    }
```

controller/Inquiries.php

Basically I just copy pasted all of them, and changes the class name from `Report` to `Inquiries` and removed some unimportant parts

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH') ) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Inquiries extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index(){
            // Bunch of query and data that returns data into $data
            $this->myci->get_report_table($data);
        }
    }
```

libraries/Myci.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH') ) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Myci {
    var $ci;
    private $session, $auth_page, $dashboard;
    public $user_role;

    function __construct() {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->session = 'logged_in_user';
        $this->auth_page = 'auth';
        $this->dashboard = '/';
        $this->user_role = $this->get_user_role();
        $this->ci->load->model('deals');
    }

    function get_report_table($data){
        $this->ci->load->library('table');

        // Bunch of codes below
    }
}
```

So the problem is, when Report.php calling `get_report_table()`, it's working fine, the table is showing and the data is correct, no problem at all.

but when Inquiries calling `get_report_table()`, then HTTP error 500 appear on the Inquiries only. only the load library is making the error, anything else is fine. so I don't know what's wrong, it's never happened before

Comment: Provide more code and I can help but at the moment there isn't enough here to make any guesses even.

Comment: Provide structures, acutal controller code etc

Comment: @AlunR please check, I already added the codes

Comment: Not sure it will help, but you should not use `$session` for a class property name. Change it to `$sess` or something. Using `$session` will definitely cause a name collision with the CI "session" library. If you **do** load the session library the call `$this->session = 'logged_in_user';` is going to cause problems.

Comment: Hi @DFriend I already rename it to `sess`, but the problem still exists, not sure why. Thanks for your tips, I'll keep it in mind :D